# How to apply component in antdesign with vue-cli and vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, antd

I already follow the instruction on the docs [here](https://www.antdv.com/docs/vue/use-with-vue-cli/).

This is what I did

```
vue create example-app
cd example-app
```

I choose the vue 3 preset.

then change the script in `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Button from 'ant-design-vue/lib/button';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';
import App from './App';

Vue.component(Button.name, Button);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

here's my `App.js` file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <a-button type="primary">Button</a-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

But why there is no Button component on the screen? all I got is blank screen

Comment: I see you updated the question to include that you are using the vue 3 preset. Have you updated the babel.config.js as per the docs?

Comment: Yup, none of that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've failed to reproduce what's mentioned here. the code works perfectly. I think probably there's something left out from your writing.

here's the working code. try compare this with yours.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-leftpad-hbi3i?file=/src/App.vue

---

For Vue 3, things are still pretty much the same. Vue 3 uses different plugin install method.

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(Antd) // same as Vue.use in Vue 2.X
app.mount('#app')
```

this code isn't mine but it shows the same thing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-antd-xzk1x?file=/src/main.js

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my fault was that I chose vue3 and followed instructions in https://antdv.com/docs/vue/getting-started/, but had to follow https://2x.antdv.com/docs/vue/getting-started

`npm i --save ant-design-vue@next`

(@next !)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just ran the project and this is the displayed result.

Steps I followed.

1. `npm install -g @vue/cli`
2. `vue create antd-demo`
3. I selected the vue2 preset
4. `cd antd-demo`
5. `npm install ant-design-vue`
6. modified src/main.js (as per docs)
7. modified src/App.vue (as per docs)
8. `npm run serve`

Comment: I already did that, but it doesn't work on vue 3 preset

Comment: Are you getting errors when you run the project?